# Creating a SWIG typemap for function that returns vector of pairs

Tags: c++, lua, swig, typemaps

I'm trying to create a getter function that returns a vector of pairs in Lua.

I have the following vector data in C++:

```
{{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}}
```

I want to return this vector as table in Lua so it can be same as the following table `t` in Lua:

```
local t = {};
t[1].value = 1
t[1].name = "a"
t[2].value = 2
t[2].name = "b"
t[3].value = 3
t[3].name = "c"
```

Here's my code :

## **"`MyBindings.h`"**

```
#include "main.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    :MyData({{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}}){}

    void getMyData(std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> *datap)
    {
        *datap = MyData;
    }
    std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> MyData;
};
```

## **"`MyBindings.i`"**

```
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%include <stl.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>

/* convert the output std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> to lua_Table */
%typemap(in, numinputs = 0) (std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> *datap) 
(std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> *tdatap = nullptr) 
%{
%}
%typemap(argout) (std::vector<pair<float, std::string>> *datap) 
{
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < $1->size(); ++i)
    {
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_pushinteger(L, static_cast<lua_Number>($1->at(i).first));
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "value");
        lua_pushstring(L, $1->at(i).second.c_str());
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "name");
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, i + 1);
    }
    SWIG_arg++;
}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

## **"`main.cpp`"**

```
#include "main.h"
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C"
{
    int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "local c = my.MyClass()\n"
                     "local t = c:getMyData()\n"
                     "print('Value : ' .. t[2].value)\n"
                     "print('Name : ' .. t[2].name)\n");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

## **The Result I Want :**

```
Value : 2
Name : b
```

## **The Result I Get :**

> vector: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)

How should I change my code to get the result I want?

Comment: (1) `*datap = MyData` leaks memory, you probably want `datap = &MyData`. (2) Do you have to use `argout`?  It's easier to return from a function.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't have to use anything. It's fine as long as it works.

Comment: Then it's really easy to solve.  I'll post an answer soon.

Comment: BTW, the problem is `*datap = MyData`.  You are dereferencing an invalid pointer here.  But you shouldn't use this solution anyway, see my answer for an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the solution is to not use output arguments (`argout`).  This is actually a general advice for C++ programming.  Output arguments were necessary in the era of C when you couldn't easily return arrays from a function by value.

After a little bit of refactoring I end up with the following:

**`MyBindings.h`**

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class MyClass {
    std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>> m_data;
public:
    MyClass() : m_data({{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {3, "c"}}) {}

    std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>> data() { return m_data; }
};
```

**`MyBindings.i`**

```cpp
%module my
%{
    #include "MyBindings.h"
%}

%typemap(out) std::vector<std::pair<float, std::string>>
{
    lua_newtable(L);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < $1.size(); ++i)
    {
        lua_newtable(L);
        lua_pushinteger(L, static_cast<lua_Number>($1.at(i).first));
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "value");
        lua_pushstring(L, $1.at(i).second.c_str());
        lua_setfield(L, -2, "name");
        lua_rawseti(L, -2, i + 1);
    }
    SWIG_arg++;
}

%include "MyBindings.h"
```

**`main.cpp`**

```cpp
#include "lua.hpp"

extern "C"
{
    int luaopen_my(lua_State *L);
}

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaopen_my(L);
    lua_settop(L, 0);
    luaL_dostring(L, "local c = my.MyClass()\n"
                     "local t = c:data()\n"
                     "print('Value : ' .. t[2].value)\n"
                     "print('Name : ' .. t[2].name)\n");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Example invocation:

```
$ swig -c++ -lua MyBindings.i
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/lua5.3 MyBindings_wrap.cxx main.cpp -llua5.3
$ ./a.out 
Value : 2
Name : b
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works like a charm. I will give you a bounty tomorrow.

Comment: I found out that it works even after I get rid of `%include <stl.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>` from `MyBindings.i`. Are these includes just not necessary?

Comment: @ZackLee These are only necessary if actually make use of the typemaps they define.  In this simple example you only use one single typemap which you define yourself, so all those %includes are just unused.

Comment: @ZackLee This actually holds for any include, be it `%include` in SWIG or `#include` in C++.  If you don't use anything from that header, just remove it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lua_pushnumber` instead of `lua_pushinteger` in `MyBindings.i` since it's a `float` type?

Comment: @ZackLee That's just copied and pasted from your question, but yes, it should be `lua_pushnumber`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you Sir! I'd appreciate if you could take a look at my other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124644/lua-table-with-string-keys-does-not-work-with-number-indexing